# NSDate dateFromString 2 months wrong?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have the following code:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormater = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormater setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"];
[dateFormater setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
[dateFormater setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];
NSDate *localDate = [dateFormater dateFromString:localUpdate];
NSDate *serverDate = [dateFormater dateFromString:serverUpdate];
```

The input strings for localUpdate and serverUpdate are:

```
2014-01-31 23:42:17
2014-02-01 00:09:37
```

When converting those from NSString to NSDate, the second one is 2 months behind?

```
2014-01-31 22:42:17 +0000
2013-12-31 23:09:37 +0000
```

Can anyone explain this?

[image: xCodelog]

Comment: With "dd" (in lower case)?

Comment: Are you sure the second date is 2014-02-01 and not 2014-01-01? With the later that could be explained.

Comment: "DD" means "day of year", not "day of month".  Bookmark the page with all the date patterns: http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-25.html#Date_Format_Patterns

Answer (score 4, accepted):

check this line:

```
[dateFormater setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"];
```

the correct date format is @"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" with "dd" not "DD"

I had the same problem once... and if the date format it's incorrect, when you use the dateFormatter, it will subtract or add one month to the date.

Answer (score 3):

Your date format string `"yyyy-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"` is not quite right.

You're telling `NSDateFormatter` to parse the `01` in your second example as the day of the year (`DD`) instead of the day of the month (`dd`), which you want instead.

```
yyyy-MM-DD HH:mm:ss
2014-02-01 00:09:37
        ^^~~~~~~~~~~~ these digits are being parsed as day of year rather
                      than as day of month
```

This is an easy mistake, and one that is confusingly hidden by your first example, in which the day of month and the day of year **are the same.**

See the [Unicode reference](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-25.html#Date_Format_Patterns) for the date formats used by iOS 6 and up. (For older versions, choose the right link in [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002369-SW13).)

Academic tangent: why `NSDateFormatter` interprets the second date as being on the last day of 2013 (rather than 1st day of 2014, as specified) is probably a bug caused by specifying a month **and** a day of year (which are mutually exclusive), a bug in the parser (interpreting the `-01`th day of the year), or a timezone or daylight savings detail (if the rules changed on midnight in the local timezone.)