# NSDate in string shows date of one month before

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I am taking date of string having format *yyyy-MM-DD* from database then converting it into NSDate having format *yyyy-MM-DD*. And again converting back it into string format *dd-MM*.

But when at last I get date in string format it shows one month before date.

Here is the code I have used:

```
   NSDateFormatter *format=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
   NSDateFormatter *format2=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];

   NSString *date;
   [format setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-DD"];
   [format2 setDateFormat:@"DD-MMM"];

   dict=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];

   for(int i=0;i<[viewHistoryData count];i++)
   {
       dict=[viewHistoryData objectAtIndex:i];


           date=[dict objectForKey:@"Date"];

       NSLog(@"My date with out format = %@",date);
       NSString *dateString =[format2 stringFromDate:[format dateFromString:date]];
       NSLog(@"My date is = %@",dateString);


       [tempArray addObject:dateString];  
   }
```

**OUTPUT**

```
2014-02-07 15:01:07.586 VirtualRunner-V3[3580:c07] My date with out format = 2014-02-07
2014-02-07 15:01:07.588 VirtualRunner-V3[3580:c07] My date is = 07-Jan
```

Does anybody know how to solve this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [NSDate dateFromString 2 months wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21491967/nsdate-datefromstring-2-months-wrong)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using the wrong placehodler for day of month. What you are using is Day of Year ranging from 1 ... 365. So instead of

```
[format setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-DD"];
```

use

```
[format setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
```

See [this link for a complete overview](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-25.html#Date_Format_Patterns).

Answer (score 0):

The format `DD` representes day of the year, not day of the month, so change your formatters to this:

```
 [format setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
 [format2 setDateFormat:@"dd-MMM"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct the two format.

```
[format setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
[format2 setDateFormat:@"dd-MMM"];
```

But I think, Issue  related with timezone. Use below to format.

```
[format2 setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT+0:00"]];
```

[See this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21601444/issue-while-trying-to-format-date/21601665#21601665)